# Is it possible to work with PostgreSQL arrays using HQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I've read a lot of topics dedicated to working with PostgreSQL arrays in Hibernate.
I implemented `UserType` interface and my queries are working perfectly fine with native sql.

```
private void addCountry(String country, String[] cities) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Query insert = session.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO public.\"countries\"(\n" +
            "\t\"country\", \"cities\")\n" +
            "\tVALUES (:Country, :Cities);");
    Type arrayType = new CustomType(new StringUserType());
    insert.setParameter("Country", country);
    insert.setParameter("Cities", cities, arrayType);

    insert.executeUpdate();
    /**
    CountriesEntity countriesEntity = new CountriesEntity();
    countriesEntity.setCountry(country);
    countriesEntity.setCities(cities);
    session.save(countriesEntity);
     */
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}

private List<String[]> listCities() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query getCities = session.createNativeQuery("SELECT \"cities\"\n" +
            "\tFROM public.\"countries\";")
            .addScalar("cities", new CustomType(new StringUserType()));

    List<String[]> cities = getCities.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return cities;
}
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries", schema = "public", catalog = "Travel_Agency")
public class CountriesEntity {
private String country;
private String[] cities;

@Id
@Column(name = "country")
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}


@Column(name = "cities")
@Type(type = "com.testHibernate.core.StringUserType")
public String[] getCities() {
    return cities;
}

public void setCity(String[] cities) {
    this.cities = cities;
}
```

}

So, is it possible to do that using only HQL?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`createSQLQuery(String queryString)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery(java.lang.String)) which creates a `SQLQuery` instance for the given **SQL** query string.

It is possible by using [`createQuery(String query)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createQuery(java.lang.String)) method, that will create a `Query` instance for the given **HQL** query string. For example retrieving a cities where city name is `cityName`:

```
Query getCities = session.createQuery("FROM countries WHERE cityName = :city ");
getCities.setParameter("city", "cityName");
return query.list();
```

Here is the documentation of [The Hibernate Query Language](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).